# iPhone: Accessing the User's Currency Symbol

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Localize Currency for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856019/localize-currency-for-iphone)

In my iPhone app, I'd like to determine the currency symbol for the region that the user is currently in.

Eg, if the user is in Europe, I'd like to display the euro symbol.  If in the US, I'd like to display the $ symbol.

Where would I be able to access this in my iPhone app?

Thanks!