# iPhone, how do I remove the localized currency format and produce a double?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've found this excellent question / answer on how localize a string with the users current currency settings... [localize-currency-for-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856019/localize-currency-for-iphone)

This is the code used...

```
NSDecimalNumber *someAmount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"5.00"];
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSLog(@"%@", [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:someAmount]);
```

However, I need to convert this to a double so I can store it to my database?

EDIT: That should read I need to convert this back to a string without the currency formating, then convert it to a double.

Comment: Using double for currency is not a good idea because converting back and forth between base 10 and base 2 can cause a loss of precision called "base conversion error".  It's better to deal with decimal numbers in base 10 strings, and instead of converting to base 2 doubles, it's best to convert base 10 strings to base 10 NSDecimal numbers.  Doing this saves the precision of the number and prevents such errors as printing customer statements for a penny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the string and call the reverse method:

```
NSNumber* number = [currencyFormatter numberFromString:string];
```