# How to change the currency type dynamically in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, currency, symbols

In my iPhone app I use a billing system. By default, the total bill amount is in `$` (US) symbol. But I want to change the currency symbol dynamically based on the country. That means, if the app user is in Europe, I need to change the currency symbol to `€`. How can I manage the localization and change the currency symbol based on the countries in my app? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Localize Currency for iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856019/localize-currency-for-iphone)

Comment: I used this code from your link, 
NSDecimalNumber *amount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10.00"];
    NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormat = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    [currencyFormat setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [currencyFormat setLocale:locale];
    NSLog(@"Amount with symbol: %@", [currencyFormat stringFromNumber:amount]);  But,it always return in '$' symbol.I have changed the time zone to 'London,england' in my iPhone, still the code return in '$ 10.00' this format.Where i am wrong.Pls help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There i found the answer for my question. This link helped me to solve my all doubts. I want to share the link so that i will help in future. The link is [Change currency symbol based on county dynamically iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8557467/1005346). Thanks.