# Incorrect result using float to represent currency values

Tags: objective-c, ios

If I use the following code:

```
- (NSString*)formatToCurrency:(float)inFloat {
  NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
  [currencyFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
  [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
  [currencyFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
  [currencyFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

  NSNumber *x = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:inFloat];
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@", [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:x]];
}
```

then pass in 203500 when calling the code, I receive the output: $203,500.02.

I'd love to hear some thoughts on what is happening.

Thanks,

Matt

EDIT: XCode was reporting 203500 when I viewed it with the debugger, but when I converted the float to an NSString, it would also show 203500.018.  Meaning the problem was in the float and not in the NSNumberFormatter.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this result, I'm getting `203,500.00`.

Comment: To give an example of @vikingosegundo .. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856019/localize-currency-for-iphone

Comment: Try it again, only change all occurrences of `float` to `double`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating the NSNumber with a float. Floats always can have a rounding error

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

You should familiarize yourself with [NSDecimals](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-BAJEJDDJ) and [NSDecimalNumbers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/DecimalNumbers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000176-CJBCAGDI)

[Cocoa is my GF: Don't be lazy with NSDecimalNumber (like me)](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/23/cocoa-tutorial-dont-be-lazy-with-nsdecimalnumber-like-me/)

Comment: +1 for `NSDecimal`, but if fractional amounts of cents are not allowed, a better solution would be to encode the dollar amount in cents instead, and use an integral value type to store it

Comment: Thanks.  I completely blanked that.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly I've lots to learn on this.  But at the risk of getting dinged further, I'll report one thing that did help me.

I had this code:

```
self.myDollarFormat.roundingIncrement = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:roundingInc];
return [self.myDollarFormat stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: dollars]];
```

And found 638198.2 with a roundingIncrement of 0.1 was yielding @"$638,198.21".

I changed my code to use double instead of float, and then I got the expected result.

```
self.myDollarFormat.roundingIncrement = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: roundingInc];
return [self.myDollarFormat stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble: dollars]];
```

I defer to those who know more, but I thought I'd at least mention this worked for me.  Good luck.